# Rails undefined method user_signed_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

Been working on getting my site up on Heroku, and realized I hadn't added `//= require_tree .` to my application.js file, which I believe is why my JS files weren't being loaded.

After adding that, I push to Heroku in production mode and get the error "undefined method 'user_signed_in?' for #<#:0x00000003fd2d18>"

I've tried changing all references to `user_signed_in?` in my views to `signed_in?(:user)` but it makes no difference. I'm running Rails 3.2.13 and this is how I am getting the Devise gem in my Gemfile:

```
gem "devise", :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
```

Any advice?

**UPDATE** - Routes.rb

```
BrainDb::Application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users

resources :submissions
get "/submissions/new(.:format)" => "submissions#new"
get "/submissions/:id(.:format)" => "submissions#show"
post "/submissions/:id(.:format)" => "submissions#update"

resources :folders

root to: 'home#index'

scope "api" do
get "/submissions(.:format)" => "submissions#index"
get "/submissions/:id(.:format)" => "submissions#show"
get "/:user_id/submissions(.:format)" => "submissions#usercontent"
get "/:user_id/submissions/:id(.:format)" => "submissions#usersubmission"



get "/:user_id/folders(.:format)" => "folders#userfolders"

get "/submissions/:id/edit(.:format)" => "submissions#edit"

get "/folders/new(.:format)" => "folders#new"

end
```

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Application.html.erb where I use it:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>

<div id="fixed_nav">
<h3 id="logo"><a href="/">chakra</a></h3>
<%= form_tag(folders_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form") do %>
    <div class="input-append">
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for anything", :class => "form-field" %>
        <button class="btn btn-edit" type="submit form-submit"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div id="settings-links">
    <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path, :method => :get %>
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
</div>
</div>

<% else %>

<div id="fixed_nav">
<h3><a href="/">chakra</a></h3>
</div>

<% end %>
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_id, :submissions, :folders
# attr_accessible :title, :body

has_many :submissions
has_many :folders

end
```

Comment: Is there a user model? Have you created a user model using devise? rails generate devise MODEL

Comment: Yes, I've been running the app locally for a few months now. Devise and user models work when I remove the require_tree line, but obviously the rest of my JS assets don't load.

Comment: Post your config/routes.rb and check devise :database_authenticatable is there in your user model.

Comment: Could you post your application.js ?

Comment: Updated with application.js and routes.rb

Comment: @techvineet - Yes, my user model does have that.

Comment: Yeah problem is with your User model. Make sure you have this line -- devise :database_authenticatable -- in your user.rb model

Comment: Can you show the code snippet where you are calling the method?

Comment: before_filter :authenticate_user! in your controller exists right ?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn - Yes, I'm assuming I need it in all the controllers that utilize user_signed_in? Do I need it in my ApplicationController?

Comment: I added a snippet from application.html.erb where I use it.

Comment: If you put it in application controller you dont have to include it in all the controllers which are inheriting from ApplicationController

Comment: Could you Post your Controller ?

Comment: Which controller? Application controller? User controller?

Comment: Added. Thanks for trying to help me, this is frustrating for me.

Comment: You seem to be missing the call to devise :database_authenticatable in your User model.

Comment: How so? It's right at the top.

Comment: Oh, missed that. Can you give us your Repo ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the method 'clear_helpers' in ApplicationController is blocking Devise to load his helpers.

Removing this Method should be your Green Light.

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
```

in your application.rb